# Roads Calculation in Python(recursive)

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I need to calculate the amount of roads that i can get from n to 0, but my code seem to work for some cases and some it don't.

edit:
when i try to execute: roads(7, 2 ,3)
it shows:

line 95 is the recursive part at the end

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 102, in <module>
  File "python", line 95, in roads
  File "python", line 95, in roads
  File "python", line 95, in roads
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

---

```
def jumps(n, j):

    if n == 0:
        return True
    elif n<0:
        return False
    else:
        if n<j:
            return False
        elif n==j:
            return True
        elif n>j:
            if n%j ==0:
                return True
            else:
                return False

def roads(n, short_jump, long_jump, memo=None):

    if memo == None:
        memo = {}

    if n not in memo:
        if n==0:
            memo[n] = 1
            return memo[n]
        elif n<0:
            memo[n] = 0
            return memo[n]
        else:
            sum_hmrm = 0

            a = jumps(n, short_jump)
            b = jumps(n, long_jump)
            c = n-long_jump
            d = n-short_jump

            if a == True:
                sum_hmrm += 1
            if b == True:
                sum_hmrm += 1

            sum_hmrm += (roads(c, short_jump, long_jump, memo) + roads(d, short_jump, long_jump, memo))

            memo[n] = sum_hmrm
            return memo[n]
```

Comment: _Which_ are the cases for which it does and doesn't work?

Comment: roads(2, 2, 3) works
roads(7, 2, 3) doesnt work

i think that my problem occurs when (n>long_jump) but i cant figure out why

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it run forever? Raise an exception? Return the wrong answer (and how do you know the right answer)?

Comment: it should return an integer, which shows in how many ways i can get from n to 0

but when the n is big enough, it throws an error that it cant add a None type to an integer

Comment: If memo serves as memorization,  you're doing it wrong. Look it up on the net. Use a decorator

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with how you're doing your memoization. The main body of your code is conditioned on `if n not in memo`. However, you don't do anything at all if that condition is not met. This means that if you try to recalculate a value that you've already evaluated, you return `None` instead of the cached value.

I think you want to remove the indented `return` lines you have, and add one at the end of the function that is not inside the `if` statement:

```
if n not in memo:
    if n==0:
        memo[n] = 1 # remove return after this line
    elif n<0:
        memo[n] = 0 # and here
    else:
        sum_hmrm = 0

        a = jumps(n, short_jump)
        b = jumps(n, long_jump)
        c = n-long_jump
        d = n-short_jump

        if a == True:
            sum_hmrm += 1
        if b == True:
            sum_hmrm += 1

        sum_hmrm += (roads(c, short_jump, long_jump, memo) + roads(d, short_jump, long_jump, memo))

        memo[n] = sum_hmrm # the one after this line can just be unindented

return memo[n]
```